# CSS JS собрать в один файл с помощью чего?

Tags: html, php, сжатие, css, javascript

С помощью чего можно собрать в один файл  `CSS` и `JS`?

Чтобы получалось в одну строку без сжатия, как бы в папке лежит несколько файлов.

В командной строке перечисляю файлы и на выходе получаю один файл.

То же самое: интересует, как получить `HTML` в одну строку, как у гугла (использую PHP Smarty)?

Answer (score 3):

[minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/)
Combines, minifies, and caches JavaScript and CSS files on demand to speed up page loads.
Наверное, самый популярное средство. Вот еще [вариант](http://habrahabr.ru/post/10500/).